# Preserve exif data of image with PIL when resize(create thumbnail)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif

When I try to resize (thumbnail) an image using PIL, the exif data is lost.

What do I have to do preserve exif data in the thumbnail image? When I searched for the same, got some links but none seem to be working.

```
from PIL import  Image
import StringIO

file_path = '/home/me/img/a.JPG'
im = Image.open( file_path)
THUMB_SIZES = [(512, 512)]
for thumbnail_size in THUMB_SIZES:
    im.thumbnail( thumbnail_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    thumbnail_buf_string = StringIO.StringIO()
    im.save('512_' + "a", "JPEG")
```

The orginal image has exif data, but image im(512_a.JPEG) doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pyexiv2
from PIL import  Image

file_path = '/home/../img/a.JPG'
metadata = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata(file_path)
metadata.read()
thumb = metadata.exif_thumbnail
thumb.set_from_file(file_path)
thumb.write_to_file('512_' + "a")
thumb.erase()
metadata.write()
```

Now I open the image using (Patch Image Inspector) , I can see the exif data

Answer (score 23):

I read throught some of the source code and found a way to make sure that the exif data is saved with the thumbnail.

When you open a jpg file in PIL, the `Image` object has an `info` attribute which is a dictionary. One of the keys is called `exif` and it has a value which is a byte string - the raw exif data from the image. You can pass this byte string to the save method and it should write the exif data to the new jpg file:

```
from PIL import Image

size = (512, 512)

im = Image.open('P4072956.jpg')
im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
exif = im.info['exif']
im.save('P4072956_thumb.jpg', exif=exif)
```

To get a human-readable version of the exif data you can do the following:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

im = Image.open('P4072956.jpg')
for k, v in im.getexif().items():
    print(TAGS.get(k, k), v)
```

Comment: I tried it but im.save('P4072956_thumb.jpg', exif=exif) not saving the exif data

Comment: Try `print exif` to confirm that there is exif data. Or you can try running the second example to view the exif data.

Comment: When I open the orginal file with 'Phatch Image Inspector' ,there is exif data,But when I open the resized image file ,with the above tool, there no exif

Comment: What happens when you run the second code example with the original image and thumbnail?

Comment: Both orginal and resized image prints the same dict!

Comment: both image has same exif printed even though I didn't pass exif to save function.

Comment: I got the solution,import pyexiv2  metadata = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata(file_path)
    metadata.read()
    thumb = metadata.exif_thumbnail
    thumb.set_from_file(file_path)
    thumb.write_to_file('512_' + "a")
    thumb.erase()
    metadata.write()

Comment: But ImageLength and ImageWidth are part of the exif data; won't they now be incorrect?

Comment: `im.save('P4072956_thumb.jpg', exif=exif)` does not write the `exif` information

Answer (score 22):

In my project, i met the same issue with you. After searching Google, I found `piexif` library. It help to `Pilow` save `exif` data to thumbnails.

You can use the source code below:

```
from PIL import  Image
import piexif
import StringIO


file_path = '/home/me/img/a.JPG'
im = Image.open( file_path)

# load exif data
exif_dict = piexif.load(im.info["exif"])
exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)

THUMB_SIZES = [(512, 512)]
for thumbnail_size in THUMB_SIZES:
    im.thumbnail( thumbnail_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    thumbnail_buf_string = StringIO.StringIO()
    # save thumbnail with exif data
    im.save('512_' + "a", "JPEG", exif=exif_bytes)
```

Note: I am using python 3.4 and ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

This works with Python 3.11 and Pillow 9.4. You can retrieve the EXIF data with `Image.getexif()` and hand over the result to `Image.save()` when saving the image. Here is an example implementation:

```
from PIL import Image


def resize_image(input_path, output_path, target_height, quality=80):
    """
    Resize an image given it's target height, adjusting the width to keep the
    aspect ratio, while preserving the EXIF data in the modified image.
    """
    original_image = Image.open(input_path)
    aspect_ratio = original_image.width / original_image.height
    target_width = int(target_height * aspect_ratio)
    resized_image = original_image.resize((target_width, target_height))
    exif = original_image.getexif()
    resized_image.save(output_path, quality=quality, exif=exif)
```

Note that other image manipulation tools like "mogrify" don't adjust the height/width EXIF data, it might even not be advised to do so, but in case you want to, here is how it could be done: After `exif = original_image.getexif()`, insert:

```
    exif.update({
        256: target_width,
        257: target_height,
        })
```