# How can I insert EXIF/other metadata into a JPEG stored in a memory buffer?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, jpeg, exif

I have created a JPEG using Python OpenCV, EXIF data being lost in the process and apparently not being able to be re-added when calling imwrite (reference: [Can't keep image exif data when editing it with opencv in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50276424/cant-keep-image-exif-data-when-editing-it-with-opencv-in-python)).

Two questions:

1. In general, how can I write the original EXIF data/new custom metadata into a JPEG that exists in memory rather than a file?
2. Would pillow/PIL be able to maintain the EXIF data and allow supplementary metadata to be added? As of 2013 (reference: [how maintain exif data of images resizes using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061222/how-maintain-exif-data-of-images-resizes-using-pil)) this did not seem possible except via a tmp file (which is not an option for me).

Thanks as ever

Comment: You have a buffer in memory which is a JPEG file and it starts with a JPEG header `0xff 0xd8` and you want to edit it in memory to add some EXIF data?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Correct - is it trivial?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand what you are trying to do, but I think you are trying to process an image with OpenCV and then re-insert the EXIF data you lost when OpenCV opened it...

So, hopefully you can do what you are already doing, but also open the image with PIL/Pillow and extract the EXIF data and then write it into the image processed by OpenCV.

```
from PIL import Image
import io

# Read your image with EXIF data using PIL/Pillow
imWithEXIF = Image.open('image.jpg')
```

You will now have a dict with the EXIF info in:

```
imWIthEXIF.info['exif']
```

You now want to write that EXIF data into your image you processed with OpenCV, so:

```
# Make memory buffer for JPEG-encoded image
buffer = io.BytesIO()

# Convert OpenCV image onto PIL Image
OpenCVImageAsPIL = Image.fromarray(OpenCVImage)

# Encode newly-created image into memory as JPEG along with EXIF from other image
OpenCVImageAsPIL.save(buffer, format='JPEG', exif=imWIthEXIF.info['exif'])
```

---

Beware... I am assuming in the code above, that `OpenCVImage` is a Numpy array and that you have called `cvtColor(cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` to go to the conventional RGB channel ordering that PIL uses rather than OpenCV's BGR channel ordering.

**Keywords**: Python, OpenCV, PIL, Pillow, EXIF, preserve, insert, copy, transfer, image, image processing, image-processing, dict, BytesIO, memory, in-memory, buffer.

Comment: Ah, easy as that, thank you so much! Use case is spot on - just also need the ability to add arbitrary EXIF tags if the standard supports it.

Comment: clarification: `imWithExif.info` is a dictionary, and imWithExif.info["exif"] is bytes.