# How to store metadata into a PNG or JPG with cv2, and restore it later?

Tags: python, opencv, png, jpeg, exif

How to save a string metadata to a PNG or JPG file written with `cv2`?

It could be EXIF or any other format, as long as we can retrieve it later, like in the example below.

Note: linked but not duplicate: [Does PNG contain EXIF data like JPG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542359/does-png-contain-exif-data-like-jpg), [How can I insert EXIF/other metadata into a JPEG stored in a memory buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56699941/how-can-i-insert-exif-other-metadata-into-a-jpeg-stored-in-a-memory-buffer)

Example:

```
import cv2, numpy as np

x = np.array([[[0, 0, 255], [0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0]],
              [[0, 0, 255], [0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0]],
              [[0, 0, 255], [0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0]]])

metadata = "gain: 0.12345"   # how to save this to the files?

cv2.imwrite("x.png", x)

cv2.imwrite("x.jpg", x)

y = cv2.imread("x.png")
print(y)

z = cv2.imread("x.jpg")
print(z)

# how to retrieve the metadata when opening the PNG or JPG files?
```

Comment: Seems that regardless of if CV2 has it, PIL/Pillow has that ability.

Comment: You can use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56700596/2836621 Or you can use `exiftool` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70708133/2836621