# Preserve EXIF after image resize and rotation then save in python

Tags: python, rotation, resize, python-imaging-library, exif

I've read another thread on SO regarding image rotation here:
[PIL thumbnail is rotating my image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228530/pil-thumbnail-is-rotating-my-image)

and I've read another thread on SO about EXIF preservation here:
[Preserve exif data of image with PIL when resize(create thumbnail)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042602/preserve-exif-data-of-image-with-pil-when-resizecreate-thumbnail)

Unfortunately, after implementing the suggestions above, it seems that I can only have either:
1) a saved rotated image without EXIF data 
or 
2) a non-rotated image with EXIF data 
but it seems that I can't have both.

I'm hoping I can get some help to fix what I thought was a real simple problem, but has been turning into a scream-fest against my computer for the past few hours.

Here's the relevant parts of my code:

```
from PIL import Image, ExifTags
import piexif
currImage = Image.open(inFileName)
exif_dict = piexif.load(currImage.info["exif"])

for orientation in ExifTags.TAGS.keys():
    if ExifTags.TAGS[orientation]=='Orientation':
        break
exif=dict(currImage._getexif().items())

if exif[orientation] == 3:
    currImage=currImage.rotate(180, expand=True)
elif exif[orientation] == 6:
    currImage=currImage.rotate(270, expand=True)
elif exif[orientation] == 8:
    currImage=currImage.rotate(90, expand=True)

currWidth, currHeight = currImage.size

# Here is where I can only do one or the other.  Don't know enough about how to get both
exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
#exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif)

maxImageDimension = [1280, 640, 360, 160]
for imgDim in maxImageDimension:
    thumbRatio = imgDim / max(currWidth, currHeight)
    # note that because Python's round function is mathematically incorrect, I have to do the following workaround
    newWidth = int(Decimal(str(thumbRatio * currWidth)).quantize(Decimal('0.'), rounding=ROUND_UP))
    newHeight = int(Decimal(str(thumbRatio * currHeight)).quantize(Decimal('0.'), rounding=ROUND_UP))
    # copy currImage object
    newImage = currImage
    # note that I have to do resize method because thumbnail method has same rounding problem
    newImage = newImage.resize((newWidth, newHeight))
    # save the thumbnail
    if imgDim == 1280:
        outFileName = destinationDir + '\\' + file[:len(file)-4] + '.jpg'
    else:
        outFileName = destinationDir + '\\' + file[:len(file)-4] + '-' + str(newWidth) + 'x' + str(newHeight) + '.jpg'
    print('Writing: ' + outFileName)

    # Here is where I have to choose between exif or exif_bytes when saving but I can only get one or the other desired result
    newImage.save(outFileName, exif=exif_bytes)  

print('\n')

currImage.close()
newImage.close()
```

Thanks in advance.